(QGIS) Saving DEM from ArcGIS ImageServer connection
I've got some LiDAR data that covers hundreds of miles that I am viewing in QGIS through an ArcGIS ImageServer connection.
I view this data as hillshading, and contours.
Once I'm connected through the image server, I right click on the layer and choose export - save as a .geotiff with the output as raw data.
The problem with this is that there is no "detail" that is saved as I am zoomed out quite a bit to try to capture all the data in the extent. If I zoom in to one small area, then there is enough detail in the exported GeoTIFF to later convert to hillshade/contours. However this isn't feasible to do in large areas. Does anyone know of a way to download the info from an ArcGIS ImageServer connection and retain all the details?
My ultimate goal is to convert this LiDAR data that covers a very large area to both hillshade, and to contour layers to then export to some sort of a file format to be able to view it in Google Earth.

So you want the server to do all the work of exporting gigabytes/terabytes of data? That's not the purpose of that service. You need to obtain the raw data and process it yourself.
